# How To Call funtion with In and Out Parameters

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a function which has Input and Output parameters both. Please see image of method asking for input and out parameters.

Please anyone guide how to call this method and get the desired output. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I have use the following code to call the method but its giving error with red line:

```
U2E.TranToEnglish(channel_inn, client_app_in, login_in, pwd_in, tp_trans_id_in, name_in, father_name_in, mother_name_in, address_1_in, address_2_in, birth_place_in, cnic_in, 
                  ref string i , ref string i1, ref string i2, ref string i3, ref string i4, ref string i5, ref string i6, ref string i7, ref string i8, ref string i9, ref string i10, ref string i11, ref string i12, ref string i13, ref string i14, ref string i15, ref string i16, ref string i17, ref string i18);
```

Comment: Image is updated now...

Comment: This method has way to many parameters, just saying...

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: _Excessive use of parameters hits you for 100 damage!_

Comment: Don't put the type in the call, i.e pass `ref i` not `ref string i`.

Comment: Why -1. This method is shared by the vendor. I prefer using datatable when returning more than one values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having input and ref parameters. Please see below example on how to provide ref parameter to a method.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string valueout="cat";
            SetString1(10, ref valueout);
        }
        static void SetString1(int value_IN,ref string value_OUT)
        {
            if (value_OUT == "cat") 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Is cat");
            }
            value_OUT = "dog"; 
        }


    }
```

So for every ref parameter you should declare the variable and initialize the value and send it to method.

Comment: Thanks, I have used the same but getting error. Please update in my first thread, thanks.

Comment: U2E.TranToEnglish(channel_inn, client_app_in, login_in, pwd_in, tp_trans_id_in, name_in, father_name_in, mother_name_in, address_1_in, address_2_in, birth_place_in, cnic_in, ref  i , ref  i1, ref  i2, ref  i3, ref  i4, ref  i5, ref  i6, ref  i7, ref  i8, ref  i9, ref  i10, ref  i11, ref  i12, ref  i13, ref  i14, ref  i15, ref  i16, ref  i17, ref  i18);

Comment: Please use the below line it will work for sure. 
U2E.TranToEnglish(channel_inn, client_app_in, login_in, pwd_in, tp_trans_id_in, name_in, father_name_in, mother_name_in, address_1_in, address_2_in, birth_place_in, cnic_in, ref i , ref i1, ref i2, ref i3, ref i4, ref i5, ref i6, ref i7, ref i8, ref i9, ref i10, ref i11, ref i12, ref i13, ref i14, ref i15, ref i16, ref i17, ref i18)

Comment: your code help me a lot to achieve what i needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

I done it and used the following code. I also really appreciates who replied to this question immediately. Following is the code that resolve my issue.

```
            string a3_first_name = "";
            string b3_last_name = "";
            string c3_type = "";
            string d3_number = "";
            string e3_dt_b = "";
            string f3_nationality = "";
            string g3_appartment = "";
            string h3_street = "";
            string i3_block = "";
            string j3_city = "";
            string k3_area = "";
            string l3_postal_code = "";
            string m3_country = "";
            string n3_birth_place = "";
            string o3_Address_2 = "";
            string p3_father_name = "";
            string q3_mother_name = "";
            string r3_aksa_train_id = "";
            string s3_message = "";

            WebReference.Service MyService = new WebReference.Service();
            MyService.Converted("MNPO", "FARZ", "DFT", "BBN&&$TS", "1", "AaMER", "Father", "Mother", "Address1", "Address2", "City", "cccet", ref a3_first_name, ref b3_last_name, ref c3_type, ref d3_number, ref e3_dt_b, ref f3_nationality, ref g3_appartment, ref h3_street, ref i3_block, ref j3_city, ref k3_area, ref l3_postal_code, ref m3_country, ref n3_birth_place, ref o3_Address_2, ref p3_father_name, ref q3_mother_name, ref r3_aksa_train_id, ref s3_message);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
U2E.TranToEnglish(channel_inn, client_app_in, login_in, pwd_in, tp_trans_id_in, name_in, father_name_in, mother_name_in, address_1_in, address_2_in, birth_place_in, cnic_in, ref i , ref i1, ref i2, ref i3, ref i4, ref i5, ref i6, ref i7, ref i8, ref i9, ref i10, ref i11, ref i12, ref i13, ref i14, ref i15, ref i16, ref i17, ref i18)
```

Comment: He is passing ref string i  . After ref no need to include datatype.So i have removed that.

Comment: That is what i changed and posted :)

Comment: To Call a method do we need to specify data type? Really?